# Calculation ignores value of 0 in PromQL

Tags: prometheus, promql

In prometheus for showing disk write usage on a chart, we use the following query:

```
sum_over_time(increase(diskWriteBytes{vid=“112345”}[1d] offset -1d )[1d:1d])
```

On diskWriteBytes, we sometimes see a value of 0.
In this query, we want to ignore the 0 value.
My attempts to handle this have failed in a variety of ways.
A prometheus version of 2.33.4 and a go version of 1.17.7 are being used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you tried to apply the comparison operators, but if I use this very similar query:

sum(increase(up[1d])) by (job)
I get a result of zero for all jobs that have not restarted over the past day and a non-zero result for jobs that have had instances restart.

If I now tack on a != 0 to the end of it, all zero values are filtered out:

sum(increase(up[1d])) by (job) != 0

Comment: Suppose we have a timeseries as diskWriteBytes that keeps diskwrite server data, but my exporter sometimes crashes and returns 0 zeros, so prmetheus saves it. I would like to ignore every diskWriteBytes{vid=“112345”} == 0 from timeseries and then calculate diskwrite bytes

Comment: Say you want to zero-out a failing hard disk. You want to overwrite as much as possible with zeros. What you don't want is: the process aborts on the first write-error. How to do that?

AFAICS, plain dd only provides an option for ignoring read errors. Thus, something like

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk/by-id/lousy-vendor-123 bs=128k
is not enough.

ddrescue seems to be better at ignoring errors - but what would be the optimal command line with it?

My try with GNU ddrescue:

ddrescue --verbose --force --no-split /dev/zero /dev/disk/by-id/lousy-vendor-123